# How to attach third-part libraries in release version

Tags: c#, macos, opencv, xamarin, emgucv

I have a program on .NET 4 for Windows. I'm trying to port it for Mac computers with mono and Xamarin studio.
I have third-part library `EmguCV` (it's a wrapper for `OpenCV` library). I'm using [official manual](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Getting_ready) to install it. It installs both `OpenCV` and `EmguCV` to

> Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/lib

When I start program in Debug mode from Xamarin - all works fine. It founds all libraries and use it. But when I make program as "pak" and run on computer without installed `EmguCV` - I got "DLL not found" exception.

I make my program with this command:

```
macpack -m:1 -o:. -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ -r:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/lib -r:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/bin -r:Assimp32.dll -r:Assimp64.dll -r:cvextern.dll -r:Emgu.CV.dll -r:Emgu.Util.dll -r:libegl.dll -r:libglesv2.dll -r:OpenTK.dll -r:OpenTK.GLControl.dll -r:RH.AssimpNet.dll -r:RH.HeadEditor.dll -r:RH.ImageListView.dll -r:RH.HeadShop.exe -r:blending.fs -r:blending.vs -r:blendingPl.vs -r:idle.fs -r:idle.vs -r:skelet.vs -r:sprite.png -r:./Libraries -r:./Models -r:./Plugin -r:./Resources -r:./Stages -r:./"Haar Cascades" -n:HeadShop -a:RH.HeadShop.exe
```

My second and third params should attached `EmguCV` libraries to my pak:

- -r:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/lib
- -r:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/bin

And when I'm looking inside pak - I find this libraries. However the program still not found it..

I guess trouble in `openCV` native libraries, but I can't realize what is wrong :(

Comment: not sure about C# ... typically you just add the DLL binaries to the working directory or to anywhere else, where the system/program can find them

Comment: Yep. For windows it's true. But for MAC it isn't working. I put all openCV dylib to my debug folder -  and got error again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I spent a lot of time on mac forums :)

The point is that OSX dynamic libraries (*.dylib) have an "install name" that tells the OS where the library expects to be found. 
So, to work with it - I should change "install name". To do it - I used a tool `dylibbundler` that changed this name with `install_name_tool` like this:

```
install_name_tool -id "@loader_path/dylibs/libcvextern.dylib" libcvextern.dylib
```

where `@loader_path` is a special Mac variable, which allows to use relative to application path.

Answer (score 1):

These are the things I'd check first.
1. Is your pak complete.  Sounds like you may have already checked that.
2. Does your test system have the opencv binaries installed and in the path.

Comment: Each users doesn't have to have a separate install of the opencv binaries but each user has to have access to where ever the opencv binaries are.  This can be achieved by ensuring the path variable contains the directory where your opencv binaries are located.  Alternatively, you can sym-link your opencv binaries to a directory location that is already in each users path.